# YAML, linting - syntax error - unknown escape character '

Tags: yaml, lint

Hello Developer Community!

I would like to ask for some help about the following, I have the following YAML data:

```
---
# yamllint disable rule:indentation rule:empty-lines
                      config_nsapp_cs_policy:
                      nsapp_cs_policy:

                          - policyname:                "url_app_preprd"
                            rule:                      "URL == \'/string/*\'"
```

When trying to run [YAML lint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) against the YAML file, I get the following error:

```
  7:69      error    syntax error: found unknown escape character "'" (syntax)
```

Is it possible to define an exception rule for this specific linting rule (ignoring the problematic content in 'single quote')? I was thinking about completely disable / ignore YAML linting for the file as a whole, but it would not be the best approach. I do not know which YAML linting rule the single quote is matching. The single quote is expected in the line.

Thank You very much in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a linter error, this is a parser error. Your input is invalid YAML because an escape sequence `\'` is not defined in YAML.

If the scalar content should simply contain single quotes, do

```yaml
    rule: "URL == '/string/*'"
```

If the scalar content should also contain the backslashes, do

```yaml
    rule: "URL == \\'/string/*\\'"
```

You can use a block scalar instead to avoid escaping the backslash:

```yaml
    rule: >-
      URL == \'/string/*\'
```

Comment: That means you need the backslash, so you should use the second or third option.

Comment: Thank You for the feedback. The problem is that, this YAML definition contains a configuration for Citrix NetScaler in the following format:

`add cs policy url_app_preprd -rule "URL == \'/string/*\'"` - This means, the YAML definition should refer to the content in the same format as stored in the NetScaler configuration.

Comment: „*the YAML definition should refer to the content in the same format*“ but it doesn't. You need to understand that if you put anything in a YAML file, it needs to adhere to the YAML format. There's no way around that. You can't go and tell the YAML parser „please allow the escape sequence `\'`, which is normally forbidden“.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing me to the right direction. After deleting the escape char before single quote, this format is also accepted by Citrix NS, while it conforms YAML format.